# I got strange response when I post data in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I get a problem when trying to throw data with the post method, but what I get is a rather strange response. As follows:[The Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3axg5.png)

[image]

Here's my code:

```
sendPostRequest() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let postData = JSON.stringify({
      grant_type:"test1",
      client_id:"test2",
      client_secret:"test3"

    });

    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/suitecrmxperuri/api/oauth/access_token", postData, requestOptions)
      .subscribe(data => {
        alert("Ini Sukses "+data['_body']);
        console.log(data['_body']);
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        alert("Ini Gagal "+error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the app, with ionic serve or ionic run ? if you are using ionic run the url "http://localhost:8080/" points to app itself

Comment: I build it to apk

Comment: So you have to point to your api ip, if its local you have to point to your computer ip (Ex: 192.168.1.x:8080)